# Go to actual photo shown on iOS wallpaper when using random shuffling

Tags: ios, photos, wallpaper

I’m using the [random shuffle function](https://www.laptopmag.com/how-to/ios-16-trick-lock-screen-random-photos) on iOS to choose a random (in my case „nature“) photo from my library as a background.

Is there a way to either

1. go to the corresponding photo currently shown as the wallpaper in the photos app
   *or*
2. see which photos are currently selected as „random“, i.e., a folder containing the sequence of photos used as wallpapers (I’ve realized that the same photos pop up over time)

Why am I asking? I have a lot of photos and sometimes would like to know where and when the currently displayed photo was taken.

Comment: “Go to actual photo currently shown” do you mean to the actual photo in the photos library? What do you mean see which photos are selected for random?

Comment: Yes, to your first question. And regarding the second one: opposite to it’s name, the random shuffling does, as far as I can tell, not actually randomly select photos. So maybe it would be possible to see this selection it chooses from somewhere.

Comment: The only way I’ve found to link back to the original photo is to long tap the background, click “Customize”, the tap the three dots at the bottom, then on the menu that pops up select “show in library”.  You have to go through editing the background to get what you’re looking for.

Comment: @Allan Nice, thank you! Not super straightforward but exactly what I’m looking for. I’ll accept it as an answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can “link back” to the photo in the library of your background photo by following these steps:

1. Long press the background photo until you get the “Photo Shuffle” screen. Don’t unlock the device!
2. Click *Customize* at the bottom
3. Select the “Lock Screen”
4. At the bottom lower right, press the elipses (three dots)
5. A context menu will appear.  Select *Show photo in Library*.  You will then be taken to the photo’s location in the Photos Library

As stated in comments, this isn’t a straight forward process, but it ultimately gets you where you want to go.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]